# Convert string to nested Ruby Hash [] get method

Tags: ruby, string, hash, nested, translate

I have a string like `'[field1][field2]'` that I need to use to access a nested field from a Hash object. Basically, I want to do `hash_obj['field1']['field2']`.

How can I transform that string to something that Ruby will understand as a symbol so that I'll be able to access the nested Hash fields?

I tried to use `.to_sym` but didn't find a way to use it. I found other posts to generate new hash objects from strings, but I couldn't find one that explained specifically the usage of a string to build up a hash field access.

Comment: Could you provide more examples of what your input string is? And what structure do you expect to have as output. A couple of examples. @perdo

Comment: The input string is something like in the format of '[field1][field2][...]'. I don't want to generate an output structure. I just need to access the key of an existing hash.

Comment: It still unclear for me unfortunately. I think your task could be resolved with regexp though. I've make a simple one: https://rubular.com/r/WiV5gSPkXd4gDR

Comment: You need to provide a minimal, complete,  executable, and testable example. As written, your question can't be executed or a so,Union validated without guessing about your data structures and input/output values.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Nor does @Vasliy. The fact that there is only one answer a day after you posted the question--and evidently that answer reflects a misunderstanding of your question--means that you need to do a better job in your statement of the question. I expect the confusion could be cleared up by adding a few examples. In any event, when requests for clarification are made in comments you should edit your question as opposed to elaborating in comments. Readers should be able to understand questions without having to read through all the comments...

Comment: ...Three examples of statements I do not understand are given in the comment you left on Vasily's answer: "...and the input string tells me which one." (how does it do so?), "...easy for non-nested fields..." (what is a "field" here and in what sense can it be "nested"?) and "... to address that key...". (what is "that" key?). Please take this as constructive criticism. Sometimes asking a question can be more difficult than answering it. Edit your question as best you can and we'll help you achieve a clear, unambiguous wording.

Answer (score 0):

1. There is no method in Ruby stdlib to turn any arbitrary string to struct (e.g. Hash).
2. The simplest way to divide a string apart is String#split that returns Array. Making a Hash from Array is much more simple task.
3. Most common answer that covers totally all cases: use regexp:

```rb
re = /\[(.*?)\]+/
s = "[field0][foo][bar]"
fields = s.scan(re).flatten
=> ["field0", "foo", "bar"]
fields.each do |field|
  your_existing_hash[field]
end
```

4. There could be a simple solutions for your task if you describe the source of your strings and it's format (all invariants). For example if your string is URL encoded params - then there is a bunch of libraries that could parse that strings.

Comment: Like I mentioned in the comment above, I don't want to generate a new structure from the input string. I just need to access a key of an existing hash and the input string tells me which one. This would be easy for non-nested fields, but I get cases where the input string is something like '[field1][field2][...][fieldX]' and I need to convert that somehow to be able to address that key in the existing hash.

Comment: @Pedro I've updated the answer with an example of using regexp.